# Connect two buldings wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-bridge

The scenario is that, Main office has got a domain and 80 user already joined it.the other office is in another building 200 meters apart.I want to make connection between them and need bandwidth like 300 mbps because of transmitting big amount of files.There 80 client in new office which should join to the domain.I will be appreciated if u can help me.

Comment: Do you have line of sight?  What is a realistic budget?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: How did you calculate that you need 300mbps?

Answer (score 2):

At this time (20 September 2013) the best appears to be Ubiquiti - it is carrier class and affordable.  We run Bullet M5s and M2s in point-to-point links and unless they run in polluted airspaces (such as the 2.4GHz band) they've never skipped a beat.

Only thing is, their products seem to max out at 150Mbps.  This has never been a problem for us as our links are usually used at sites with a 2mbps choke point (and our users rarely need to transfer large files), but you could try running a pair of links and using LACP on switches on either end to combine the bandwidth to your desired 300Mbps goal.  I can't vouch for whether this works, but others may have tried it - look for details at your nearest [Google](http://www.google.com).

Before you go buying any wireless hardware, I strongly recommend going to http://www.ubnt.com/airlink and putting the two locations into there to see if you have enough height for a good link - bad things tend to happen if you don't check first.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: There is also the more expensive airFiber range - they are pricy, but you can push in excess of 1.4Gbps across a link if the conditions are right.

EDIT the second: The NanoStation M5 can do 300mbps.

Comment: Laser and Microwave links are other options. I don't have any experience but no doubt (significantly?) more expensive than wireless options, but I believe they are capable of more reliable performance and higher throughput (the old Good vs Fast vs Cheap triangle...!)

Comment: Thanks Aaron ,im just getting familiar with this technology(airfiber),interesting

Answer (score 0):

By far the best and most reliable way to do it, and the way that it is done properly by businesses who have a sufficient IT budget to function, is to run fibre (if a campus) or lease a private fibre or MPLS circuit between the two buildings, and route inter-building traffic over it.

If you insist on doing this wirelessly, you could probably use a pair of wireless N radios (eg. APs), which happen to function at a nominal speed of 300mbps usually, and some high-gain parabolic dish antennae.  Make one a client and another a base station, using your platform of choice, make them routers, and route accordingly.  Keep in mind this will be troubled by rain, radio noise, and distance.

There are also products you can buy that will help you do this, though I'm not going to name a specific vendor because that tends to change and I can't really endorse one over another.